# How to fix ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called on flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, request, pypdf

I want to try to make a dataframe from pdfreader, with the column name is isi1. but why do I get an error ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called !. what should i do to fix this error. help from anyone when needed for this problem.
this is my code

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['file']
        f.save(f.filename)
        pdfreader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open('C:/Users/Novilia/PycharmProjects/tesaja/' + f.filename, 'rb'))
        from pandas import DataFrame
        df1 = DataFrame(pdfreader, columns=['isi1'])
        #vect = count_vect.transform(['isi1']).toarray()
        df1['label1'] = text_clf.predict(df1['isi1'])
        df1.append(['label1'])
        hasil = (df1.isi1[df1['label1'] == 'positif'])
        len(hasil)
        hasil_list = hasil.values.tolist()
        stringList = ' '.join([str(item) for item in hasil_list])
        hasil_ringkas = stringList

    return render_template('result.html', ringkasan = hasil_ringkas)
```

the error is

```
ValueError
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "C:\Users\Novilia\PycharmProjects\tesaja\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2463, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Users\Novilia\PycharmProjects\tesaja\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\Novilia\PycharmProjects\tesaja\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Users\Novilia\PycharmProjects\tesaja\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\Novilia\PycharmProjects\tesaja\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\Novilia\PycharmProjects\tesaja\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\Novilia\PycharmProjects\tesaja\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Users\Novilia\PycharmProjects\tesaja\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\Novilia\PycharmProjects\tesaja\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\Novilia\PycharmProjects\tesaja\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "C:\Users\Novilia\PycharmProjects\tesaja\app.py", line 79, in summarize
df1 = DataFrame(pdfreader, columns=['isi1'])
File "C:\Users\Novilia\PycharmProjects\tesaja\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 509, in __init__
raise ValueError("DataFrame constructor not properly called!")
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

Comment: what output do you get when you print `pdfreader`

Comment: the output is object, i don't know, I just tried to extract uploaded file from request.file using PyPDF2 and then data will append at dataframe to predict label. @Jeril

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, I guess you need to iterate over the pages and get the text from each page. can you try the following:

```
import nltk

pdfreader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open('C:/Users/Novilia/PycharmProjects/tesaja/' + f.filename, 'rb'))
page_contents = [sent for page_no in range(pdfreader.getNumPages())
                 for sent in nltk.sent_tokenize(pdfreader.getPage(page_no).extractText())]
df1 = DataFrame(page_contents, columns=['isi1'])
```

Kindly let me know if you find any problem with the code.

Comment: how extract file by sentences, because output of the code is extract by page of pdf.

Comment: I want to extract based on the sentence from each ('.'), the code above produces text that is not from 1 sentence but based on the file position line. so there is 1 sentence that can be 3-4 sentences from the code above.

Comment: i have updated the solution, you can also remove the answer that you had postd